# SimplePostTool: FATAL: Connection error (is Solr running at http://localhost:8983/solr/update ?)

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I am beginner in Solr. I installed Solr 1.4.1 on Tomcat 7 on Windows 7.
Installation was successful I can reach http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/ page.

but when I am trying to post some test XMLs I have this weird error.

```
C:\Users\Bohdan\Downloads\apache-solr-1.4.1\apache-solr-1.4.1\example\exampledocs>java -jar post.jar solr.xml
SimplePostTool: version 1.2
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Make sure your XML documents are encoded in UTF-8, other encodings are not currently supported
SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: POSTing file solr.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Connection error (is Solr running at http://localhost:8983/solr/update ?): java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

C:\Users\Bohdan\Downloads\apache-solr-1.4.1\apache-solr-1.4.1\example\exampledocs>
```

Unfortunately I can not find answer in the internet. May be somebody knows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a good look at the error message. The expected port is 8983, but your port is 8080, so it can't connect.

If you want to post to port 8080, you can do so by defining `-Durl="http://localhost:8080/solr/update"`

Comment: you are right
but I do not how to change it...
there is only one jar file to post with no configuration.

Comment: here is the solution java -Durl=localhost:8080/solr/update -jar post.jar solr.xml

Comment: In my case it needed to be: java -Durl=http://localhost:8080/solr/update -jar post.jar solr.xml monitor.xml

Comment: It generates following error: SimplePostTool version 1.5
SimplePostTool: FATAL: System Property 'url' is not a valid URL: localhost:8080/solr/update

Comment: this is not working, not the other comments, gives me the error mentioned in Shah's comment